# Media main image not changes with swatches magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-images, color-swatches

I have facing some issues with configurable product. when i click on swatches main image not changed. my magento is 2.0.2.

can you please help to resolve the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading individual images for each simple product on your Magento 2 site?

Here's an example of individual images that are part of a configurable product, using Magento's sample data set:
[image: Magento Sample Data set - simple products]

If that is how you uploaded the products and the images are still not showing up, I'd make sure to clear cache, re-index, and (depending on the mode - developer / production / default) check on static deployment.

Let me know if that works?

Comment: checking with category page working fine but not working on  PDP page. As per category page getting image on last response but on detail page no one any call for image. and also swatches/ajax/media call first and getting response with images array. can you please suggest me for resolve the issue ?